# Webview2 Invalid X-Frame-Options header encountered when loading from Html

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, x-frame-options, webview2

I am using WPF application and integrated the webview2, I load the html file which have the youtube url . But some how i am getting error in console :
**"Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'xyz.com/': 'ALLOW-FROM' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored."**
I have checked the [x-frame-options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/http/headers/x-frame-options) , but somehow I am not able to understand the integration with respect to webview2.

Comment: What if you load the page in your browser and check the console?

Answer (score 0):

The setting ALLOW-FROM is not supported by most browsers. With the imminent retirement of IE11, support for it is soon history.

It is better to use the more flexible frame-ancestors directive of Content-Security-Policy. You can use this response header instead:

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors xyz.com;
```

This would allow xyz.com to frame your site.